# difference between yaw and orientation of a vehicle

Tags: ros, yaw

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the difference between yaw and orientation of a car. I know the difference between the orientation and the steering angle of a car. How is yaw related to both of them ? Also is yaw rate same as angular velocity of the car?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228128/difference-between-yaw-and-orientation-of-a-vehicle/) by [mayank_m](https://answers.ros.org/users/24140/mayank_m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2016-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Orientation is a high-level term. It includes roll, pitch and yaw if you are representing orientation with [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles). If you are representing orientation with [Quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation), it includes x, y, z, and w corresponding to Quaternion components.

In other words, yaw is only one component of orientation.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mayank_m](https://answers.ros.org/users/24140/mayank_m/) on 2016-03-03**:
So yaw is entirely different from steering angle of the car ?

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2016-03-03**:
Exactly. Different, but related of course. Steering angle results in lateral force on wheels and this force results in yaw motion.